# WebPack final build output folder is empty

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

Can’t resolve how to compel a WebPack 3.6 to build a final *dist*.
Simply the output folder is empty. With given config the application is built and running in browser memory, however *dist* folder is empty and there is now any physical files.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const staticSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'static');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname);
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: {
        /*base: path.resolve(staticSourcePath, 'src/sass/base.scss'),*/
        app: path.resolve(sourcePath, 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            sourcePath,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.[chunkhash].js',
            minChunks (module) {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
            }
        }),
      /*  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unused: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            }
        }),*/
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: [
                            'last 3 version',
                            'ie >= 10'
                        ]
                    })
                ],
                context: staticSourcePath
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            path: buildPath,
            excludeChunks: ['base'],
            filename: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true
            }
        }),
        new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'script',
            include: 'all',
            fileBlacklist: [/\.(css|map)$/, /base?.+/]
        }),
        new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            defaultAttribute: 'defer'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            allChunks: true
        }),
       /* new StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            minify: true
        }),*/
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ],
    module: {



        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react']
                  }
                },
                include: sourcePath
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot?.+|svg?.+|ttf?.+|otf?.+|woff?.+|woff2?.+)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    'url-loader?limit=20480&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
                ],
                include: staticSourcePath
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And the project structure looks like:

```
D:\project_name
├───components
│   └───villages
│       └───neighborhoods
│           └───blocks
│               └───houses
├───css
│   └───404
│       └───font-awesome
│           ├───css
│           └───fonts
├───dist
├───flags
│   ├───1x1
│   └───4x3
├───fonts
│   ├───Raleway
│   └───roboto
├───icons
├───images
│   └───slides
├───img
│   ├───404
│   │   ├───demo
│   │   └───slides
│   └───works
│       └───thumbs
├───node_modules
│   └───...
├───js
│   └───404
└──index.html
└──index.js
└──package.json
└──webpack.config.js
```

I’m running it through Windows CMD

Comment: can you show me what is your command line script to execute this config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you tagged, **webpack-dev-server**, as far as i know it does not put files in your dist directory, it's just for developing preview, so it handels the build files internally to only build parts that changed,

to build for production use: `webpack -p`

Comment: ah, yeah, it's my lack of knowledge :)  The files which are built with `webpack -p`command in `dist` folder are ready to be uploaded straight to the production server? No any additional tweaks needed?

Comment: yes, they "normaly" are production ready - but this depends on your projekt of course.

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this `webpack -p`. I am having same issue

Comment: @VipulTyagi depends on your setup, most likely you have a npm script set up in package.json you can run something like `npm run build -- -p` where build is the name of the script or you [set the mode in the config file](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode)

Answer (score 2):

You can add in your config file additional parameter:

```
devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
}
```

With that property you will in your `./dist` folder all compiled files.